# Android convert array of months

Tags: android, sqlite, date, achartengine

I get an Array of months since my SQLite database, now I want to see months in the chart aChartEngine with the long name. How do I?

```
String sql = "SELECT strftime('%m',"+Table.DATE+") AS month";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
        int count = c.getCount();
String[] months= new String[count];
for(int i=0; i<count; i++) {
            c.moveToNext();     
            months[i] = c.getString(0);  
        }


        for(int i=0;i<months.length;i++){
        multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, months[i]);            
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getDefault();
Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(timezone);
for(int i=0;i<months.length;i++){
   int monthNumber=Integer.valueOf(months[i])-1;
   calendar.set(2014, monthNumber, 1, 1, 1, 1);
   String monthName=calendar.getDisplayName(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.LONG, Locale.getDefault());
   multiRenderer.addXTextLabel(i+1, monthName);       
}
```